# How to set directory mappings for Koala for the whole folder?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to set directory mappings for [Koala prepocessor](http://koala-app.com/) to output all files into `css` folder.

My project file structure:

```
-- Project folder
  -- css
    -- style.css
    -- print.css
  -- scss
    -- style.scss
    -- print.scss
```

I would like Koala to watch for all files in `scss` folder and output them into `css` folder.

I've found it is possible with project settings file `koala-config.json` placed in the root of the project: https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki/Using-project-settings

When I tried that, it won't work:

```
// The mappings of source directory and output directory
"mappings": [
{
    "src": "scss",
    "dest": "css"
    }
],
```

How to set output mappings for the whole folder?

Comment: your example code is set to the whole folder. it means: compile everything from scss to css folder. If you create a config file, create it form the GUI, then edit it, remove the project from the koala, then readd it, but be sure you add that dir, where is the config file. For me it seems koala doesn't reload the config files, it has just some meaning when you newly add your project to the koala (and only that case, if there's no parse error, if there's parse error the whole file is ignored).

Answer (score 3):

Per-Project Settings

The previous Settings applies to all registered projects. We can also customize the Settings for per-project basis this way:

Right-click the project folder. Navigate to Project Settings > New Settings.

[image]

There are a number of options. Selecting “Default”, “for LESS”, and “for CoffeeScript” creates a project config file, koala-config.json whereas selecting "for Sass" or "for Compass" will create config.rb, the Sass and Compass config file.

These files are saved in the project root directory, and we need to edit them in a code editor to customize the Project Setting. Here is an example if you want to change the LESS output folder.

```
"mappings": [
{   
    "src": "build/less",
    "dest": "assets/css"
}],
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question?  The OP wants to configure Koala to watch the entire directory, not change the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is not new, but The Koala documentation is not extensive so maybe this code will help someone. It looks like you have to change both paths for it to work:

```
"mappings": [
     {
        "src": ".",
        "dest": "../css"
     }
],
```

You can see the actual output path in Koala's UI. It's below each SCSS file's name. Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Right Click the scss file you want to compile and you will see Set output path' option. 
Set this to destination css folder and get going. 
Also you can set per project settings by right clicking the selected scss folder in koala and selecting per project settings for SASS. Koala creates koala-config.json.

```
// The mappings of source directory and output directory
"mappings": [
    // {    
    //  "src": "path/to/source",
    //  "dest": "path/to/output"
    // }
],
```

Just edit the paths to scss and css folders.